# How to access Dynamics 365 (crm online instance) user with security role through powershell

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, crm, powershell-4.0, dynamics-crm-online

I had installed all the packages installation as mentioned in [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689040.aspx).

But I don't know how to find command/functions for it through help.

An example to access user security role (in instance) is also not there.
Can anyone suggest how to do it?